# how to get nearby sublocalities within the radius from maps api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps, bing-maps

I want the sublocalities around a point (latitude/longitude) within some specified radius. I've tried to use the google maps api and bing maps api but I'm not able to find how can I get the filtered only data from there and how to get the useful data.

Comment: Can you provide more details, perhaps a example of your input and expected output

Comment: I have input of location coordinates(lattitude,longitude) and radius (in meters) and expected output the list of names of the sublocalities in the given radius of location coordinates(the name of all the sublocalities lies in the particular radius).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want a list of all cities/towns that are within a certain distance of a coordinate. There isn't a good API for this that I'm aware of. You could download the list of cities from GeoNames and then do a search against that, but that is just point based data. You could also create a grid of points and then reverse geocode those and get the cities/towns that way.